# How to update 100,000 record MySQL database efficiently

Tags: php, mysql

I have to update a 100,000 + MySQL database from PHP that pulls data from an API. It fails if I try and do more than 5,000 at the time.

I'm thinking the best approach might be to do 5,000 by using an update query with a limit 0, 5000 and then timestamping these records with the time they are updated. Then, select the next 5,000 where the time last updated is over 20 minues since current time.

Can anyone please offer any help on how to construct this query? Or is this approach not optimal?

Comment: "fails" how? what's the query?

Comment: If it is failing from a timeout, you can try http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Rather than fool around with the timestamp, I'd just add an extra column temporarily.  But first, what's the error you're getting?

Comment: For a small database, why not do one record at a time?

Comment: I get a Content Encoding Error or a HTTP Error 500 Internal server error which I think is due to the API or likely due to a timeout. How would I use the extra column? Thanks for taking an interest

Comment: to vague a question, specific questions get specific answers

Comment: Please give your update query, you can update the table using MYSQL, why do you have to do it throught API.

Comment: Naveen, I'm getting data from an API that returns data in a JSON feed. I first loop through each of the 100,000k records to get an ID and pass this to a restful api to return the data, I then parse this and update the records in MySql

Comment: I've edited the question a bit. I don't think it's inordinately vague, but I found it a little difficult to read initially, so I can see why some would be a bit confused by it.

Comment: Thanks Tim, with hindsight I should have been clearer

Answer (score 1):

So this is the solution I have gone with, rightly or wrongly it works. So to recap the problem, I have 100k rows, I need to loop through these and pass a userid to an API that returns a json feed.

I use the data returned to update each record. For some reason this fails either becasue of a timeout or server 500 error which I believe to be due to the API. So instead of selecting all 100k reords, I just select 5k (limit 0, 5000) and add a column called 'updated' and mark this as true once it has updated.

I keep doing this until all records are updated. When this happens I set the updated column to false and start the process again. This script runs on a chron job every 30 minutes and seems to work fine. I guess I could discover why it was timing out in the first place but I suspect it could be a php ini issue (timeout setting) which I don'thave access to.

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table, multi insert the update data and then

```
UPDATE `table`, `tmp`
    SET `table`.`column` = `tmp`.`column`
    WHERE `table`.`id` = `tmp`.`id`;
```

Comment: I don't think it's a mysql issue, more that the APi I'm hitting is failing and can't handle more than 5,000 at a time. So I was looking for someway to batch the 100,000 records in 5,000 batches and cyle through them at set intervals during the day. Thanks Jonathan